# Green Coloured Titles are showing in my Django Project Files, Atom Text Editor

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

My Working project files are showing with green color titles in Atom Text Editor.

See the Screenshot of Atom Text Editor:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yEPig9oO-aHBCqorOAWe_5nlnH9l6-vX

EDIT:
I have noticed that only the viewed files are showing the color change.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly. Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Comment: @Brien Okay Brien. Thanks :)

Comment: The color refers to their (or, in the case of folders, their descendants’) Git status: orange for modified, green for new, red for deleted.